# Dropbox is not displayed in the filepicker dialog window

Tags: filepicker.io, filepicker

we are using filepicker and it works fine. But we are not able to upload the files by using the dropbox as it is not displayed in the filepicker dialog window.

we set the services as
 services: ['COMPUTER', 'GMAIL', 'DROPBOX', 'SKYDRIVE', 'CUSTOMSOURCE'],

we are able to see all other except dropbox.

Any help on this is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

From some time Filepicker require your own Dropbox app to connect. So first you need to create Dropbox app, then set dropbox keys in filepicker panel.
Here you can find more details https://developers.filepicker.com/docs/support/integration/3
https://www.filepicker.com/documentation/services/dropbox_doc

Comment: But this opens only one dropbox account which is connected

Comment: It is just example. Please go through 'Setting up a Custom Dropbox oauth application' part to set your Dropbox integration.